# Проблема с кастомными ошибками в Python

Tags: python, обработка-ошибок

Пробовал реализовать обработку кастомных ошибок в игре "крестики-нолики" через консоль, написал для них классы и функции, но ошибки не проверяются. Я начинающий программист, помогите, пожалуйста, кто знает, что нужно сделать. Прикрепляю кусок кода. На вход функции подается значение введенное пользователем, X или O в зависимости от того, чей сейчас ход, и список из чисел от 1 до 9.

```
class ValueErrror(Exception):
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "Введите число в диапазоне (1,9)"


class ValueNotInRangeError(Exception):
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "Число должно быть в диапазоне (1,9)"


# проверяем значение пользователя на соответствие условиям игры
def check_value_int(user_input: str) -> None:
    try:
        answer = int(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueErrror


# проверяем значение пользователя на соответствие условиям игры
def check_value_range(answer: int) -> None:
    try:
        answer >= 1 and answer <= 9
    except IndexError:
        raise ValueNotInRangeError


# принимаем значение пользователя и проверяем его на соответствие условиям игры
def check_entry(user_input: str, token: str, board: List[Union[str, int]]) -> Union[str, List[Union[str, int]]]:
    while True:
        try:
            check_value_int(user_input)
        except ValueErrror as i:
            return i
        else:
            answer = int(user_input)
            try:
                check_value_range(answer)
            except ValueNotInRangeError as r:
                return r
            else:
                if str(board[answer-1]) not in "XO":
                    board[answer-1] = token
                    break
                else:
                        return "Эта клетка уже занята"
    return board
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А  так задумано, что функция check_entry возвращает ошибки, а не выбрасывает их? Может нужно заменить return на raise?

Comment: @Alpensin, да, было задание, написать тесты для всех важных функций программы, и я вывел печать в отдельную функцию:

Comment: А что значит "не проверяются"? Поставьте везде `print` какой-нибудь, да посмотрите, куда попадает управление, а куда нет

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо за совет! Долго сидел и разобрался, ошибка была не в этом куске кода... моя программа печатала ошибку, если тип функции check_entry - строка, но так как я определил новый класс исключений, то и типом этой функции будет не строка, а класс, исправил и все заработало, спасибо)